# How to display the new image after some time delay under the old image that is already displaying in tkinter window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, canvas, tkinter-canvas

I want to display two image `pic1.png` and `pic2.png` on canvas using tkinter. The first image (`pic2.png`) would be already display on tkinter window. However, the second image (`pic1.png`) will be appeared after 1 second and would be behind the first image.

To achieve this, I wrote this code,

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

canvas = Canvas(frame, width=250, height=250, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge')
canvas.pack()

my_pic1 = PhotoImage(file="my_pic1.png")
frame.after(1000, lambda : canvas.create_image(50,50,image=my_pic1, anchor=NW, tag="A"))

my_pic2 = PhotoImage(file="my_pic2.png")
canvas.create_image(50,50,image=my_pic2, anchor=NW, tags="B")

canvas.tag_raise("B")
canvas.tag_lower("A")

root.mainloop()
```

But I am getting problem to place the second image(`pic1.png`) behind the first image (`pic2.png`). What I'm achieving is the second image (`pic1.png`) appears on above the first image (`pic2.png`). Please help me out in my code.

Comment: behind? You mean the 1st image will be covering the second image?

Comment: Yes Exactly! The size of the second image is little larger as compared with the first image so it would be seen even when it is behind the first image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `canvas.tag_lower("A")` is executed, image with tag "A" has not yet been created because it is scheduled to be created one second later.

You should call it after creating the image:

```py
frame.after(1000, lambda: (canvas.create_image(50,50,image=my_pic1, anchor=NW, tag="A"), canvas.tag_lower("A")))
```

Comment: Bunch of Thanks!  It works! But when I'm adding a background image in canvas, the image with the tag "A" displays even behind the background image and can't be display. What to do in this case ?

Comment: Use `canvas.tag_lower("A", "B")` to make "A" below "B".

Comment: Amazing! Thank you soo much!